# R error QP:not a positive definite matrix?

Tags: r, quadprog

Im trying to solve the following problem in R, using the quadprog package:

```
min: vec %*% p + t(p) %*% mat %*% p 
st: p >= 0
```

where

```
mat <- matrix(c(1162296,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,951.7089,0,1,0,-951.7089,0,0,1),4)
vec <- c(6341934541.1,175800.1,-356401.7,14398073047.1)
```

I've used

```
libary(quadprog)
solve.QP(2*mat,-vec, diag(4), integer(4))
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in solve.QP(2*mat, -vec, diag(4), integer(4)) : 
  matrix D in quadratic function is not positive definite!
```

However, cleary

```
> eigen(mat)$values > 0
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

What am I doing wrong? How come this error keeps showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix `mat` is not symmetric.  The `quadprog` package is designed to solve quadratic programs, which by definition, require a symmetric matrix in the highest order term.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Problem_formulation), for example.

To solve this problem as written, you will need to use a general constrained optimization algorithm.  For example, you can try `constrOptim` as so:

```
# system matrices
mat <- matrix(c(1162296,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,951.7089,0,1,0,-951.7089,0,0,1),4)
vec <- c(6341934541.1,175800.1,-356401.7,14398073047.1)

# an initial value
p0 <- c(1,1,1,1)

# the objective function
objective <- function(p) {
  vec %*% p + t(p) %*% mat %*% p
}

# solve -- warning!  without additional work you won't know if this is a global minimum solution.
solution <- constrOptim(p0, objective, NULL, diag(4), c(0,0,0,0))
```